# Understanding scikit learn import variants

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import

Scikit learn import statements in their tutorials are on the form

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
```

Another versions that works is

```
import sklearn.decomposition
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components = 2)
```

However

```
import sklearn
pca = sklearn.decomposition.PCA(n_components = 2)
```

does not, and complains

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'decomposition'
```

Why is this, and how can I predict which ones will work and not so i don't have to test around? If the understanding and predictiveness extends to python packages in general that would be the best.

Comment: Skimmed related documentation 
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html
without success. I might have missed it though.

Comment: Can you add the link of what are you following. The documentation https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/decomposition/plot_pca_iris.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-decomposition-plot-pca-iris-py here tells importing as ```from sklearn import decomposition``` then using like ```pca = decomposition.PCA(n_components=3)```

Comment: I think I based this mostly off of https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html. It imports multiple things and consistently uses 'from sklearn.submodule import function'. Clicking through some other random documentation now, you are right that 'from sklearn import submodule' is also frequently used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sklearn` doesn't automatically import its submodules. If you want to use `sklearn.<SUBMODULE>`, then you will need to import it explicitly e.g. `import sklearn.<SUBMODULE>`. Then you can use it without any further imports like `result = sklearn.<SUBMODULE>.function(...)`.

Large packages often behave this way where they don't automatically import all the submodules.

Comment: Thank you! Why do large packages tend to not import submodules automatically? Is it a memory or load time concern?

Comment: You're welcome @Anton, thanks for the upvote. Yes, both memory and load time are factors. Memory and load-time efficiency become worse if the submodules are automatically loaded; by specifying the submodule explicitly it saves on memory consumption and minimises the start-up time. I think namespace cluttering is another consideration, where explicit imports reduce the chance of naming conflicts and help maintain clarity about the specific functionality being used.